# spellcheck-service.cloudhub.io/spellcheck times out from the MuleSoft mule beginner tutorial

Tags: mule, spell-checking, cloudhub

I'm trying to run the program from the beginner tutorial on mulesoft, with the spell check service. I don't know what seems to be going wrong but it seems to time out, I get a mule_error--2.  I think the spell check cloud hub service is not running...

This is the result:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'spellchecker'                               +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2013-07-25 15:41:33,413 [[spellchecker].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\Users\mahmadzada\Desktop\mule\MuleStudio\examples\SpellChecker\InXML\spellcheck.xml
INFO  2013-07-25 15:41:33,463 [[spellchecker].SpellCheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2013-07-25 15:41:33,466 [[spellchecker].SpellCheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2013-07-25 15:41:33,475 [[spellchecker].SpellCheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2013-07-25 15:41:33,476 [[spellchecker].SpellCheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.212447412'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-07-25 15:41:33,478 [[spellchecker].SpellCheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.212447412'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-07-25 15:41:33,494 [[spellchecker].SpellCheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest: Content-Type not set on outgoing request, defaulting to: text/plain
ERROR 2013-07-25 15:41:44,065 [[spellchecker].SpellCheckerFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://spellcheck-service.cloudhub.io/spellcheck:80, connector=HttpConnector
{
  name=connector.http.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=ece5b80
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[http]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.http.spellcheck.service.cloudhub.io.spellcheck.80', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={http.method=POST}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Read timed out (java.net.SocketTimeoutException)
  java.net.SocketInputStream:-2 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://spellcheck-service.cloudhub.io/spellcheck:80, connector=HttpConnector
{
  name=connector.http.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=ece5b80
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[http]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.http.spellcheck.service.cloudhub.io.spellcheck.80', mep=REQUEST_RESPONSE, properties={http.method=POST}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher:155 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Indeed, there's an issue with http://spellcheck-service.cloudhub.io/spellcheck ... curling it times out too. I'll ping MuleSoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service was in limbo.

MuleSoft has applied CPR to it and you should be good now.

Comment: I was trying to run the program from the beginner tutorial today, getting the same problem as OP. Is the service in limbo again?

Comment: Yes, and MuleSoft knows about it.