# Mule Studio Basic Tutorial, fails on cloudhub timeout

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I was running the Mule Studio Basic Tutorial, found here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Basic+Studio+Tutorial

I ran into the same problem as the poster of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867363/spellcheck-service-cloudhub-io-spellcheck-times-out-from-the-mulesoft-mule-begin)

Seems it was fixed at some point, but the same problem is occuring again now, - seems like the service on cloudhub is not responding. Is this just an instability in Mulesofts cloudhub installation, or is there anything i can do to get around it?

Comment: BTW, the spellcheck-service.cloudhub.io/spellcheck service seem to be needed also for the intermediate and advanced tutorial, so the whole suite of Mule Studio tutorials seem a bit meaningless without access to this service

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the availability of a web-based service and is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears, the service spellcheck-service.cloudhub.io/spellcheck is now up and running again, and the Mule Studio tutorials works.